# MFC Drawing a Line on one image from a set of images

Tags: image, mfc, line, dicom

I am reading a DICOMDIR and then displaying all the images of a given series one by one, either by scrolling with the mouse or by pressing the keyboard arrow keys up n down.

Now, I happen to draw a line on one of these images. 
Currently, when I scroll through the images the line continues to stay on through all the images.

But the desired result is, when I start scrolling, that line should disappear because it does not belong to the next image. When I scroll back up to that image where I drew that line, the line should be shown back on that image.

Any ideas how to make that line part of only that image where it is first drawn and none else?

What I tried : Store the file path of that image (where the line is drawn) into a CStringArray. How should I use this stored file path to draw that image along with its line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. If you mean you want a line annotation for a particular image you can store it as GSPS data, read that also along with the pixel data. GreyScale Presentation State object
allows inclusion of multiple graphic annotation seqences into a single object.

#### Your way

As you have stored the path of the file in a CStringArray, locate the code where the image is read and displayed. Add code similar to this ( I assume that you are displaying it as you read it.) Take a look at the following code.

```
// Code to read the file where path is csFilePath
// Read bitmap is stored to CBitmap* pBitmap
CDC* pDC = GetDC();
CDC memDC;
memDC.CreateCompatibleDC( pDC );
CBitmap* pOldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject( pBitmap );
pDC->BitBlt( xVal, yVAl, width, height, memDc, SRC_COPY );
memDC.SelectObject( pOldBitmap );
memDC.DeleteObject();
for( int nIdx; nIdx < yourLineArray.GetSize(); nIdx++ )
{
    if( csFilePath == yourLineArray[nIdx] )
    {
        pDC->DrawLine( x1, y1, x2, y2 );
        break;
    }
}
```